# Order of operators and numbers inside a bracket

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space

I had an argument with my professor.

Let $H$ be an operator (e.g. hamiltonian).
Let capital $X$ denote the position operator. 
Let $f$ and $g$ be functions of $X$ that do NOT commute with $H$.

Now consider a matrix elements of $\, f(X) H g(X) \, $ in the position basis:

$$ M = \langle x| f(X) H g(X) |x'\rangle = f(x) g(x') \langle x| H |x' \rangle $$

So far so good?

Now note that $f(x)g(x')$ are just numbers. Thus

$$ M = f(x) g(x') \langle x| H |x' \rangle  = \langle x| H f(x) g(x') |x'\rangle $$

I.e. I just put the number to the right of $H$. 
Even though the operators $ \, f(X),g(X)$ do not commute with $H$, the quantities $f(x),g(x)$ are just numbers, so we can put them wherever we like.

Surely this must be allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you write is correct and there is no inconsistency. When you write $\left<x\right|Hf(x)g(x′)\left|x′\right>$ you just, indeed, put the numbers on the right. But numbers commute so there is nothign wrong with it. Note that you have really no conclusion from it.

You can't even transform back to operators on the form $\left<x\right|Hf(X)g(X′)\left|x′\right>$. There you would have gained something but this you can't do.

This is not really quantum mechanics but rather linear alrgebra and you can always look at the picture from a standard linear algebra point of view.

You have a product of three matrices $F$, $H$ and $G$. Let us call $A=FHG$. The entry $(m,n)$ in some basis is $A_{mn}=\sum_{i,j}F_{mi}H_{ij}G_{jn}$. If in this basis $F$ and $G$ are diagonal (as you assume by saying they are functions of the position alone) then you have $A_{mn}=F_{mm}G_{nn}H_{mn}$. This is the form you wrote $f(x)g(x')\left<x\right|H\left|x′\right>$.

The later form you are just rearanging the terms to say $A_{mn}=(HF_{mm}G_{nn})_{mn}$ where $HF_{mm}G_{nn}$ is a matrix obtained by multiplying two numbers $F_{mm}G_{nn}$. Therefore you are saying that $A_{mn}$ is the entry $mn$ of the matrix $HF_{mm}G_{nn}$. Again you draw no conclusions regarding the commutation between $H$ and the other two matrices.

Comment: Thank you! Turns out the professor had just mixed things up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're assuming that $|x' \rangle$ and $\langle x|$ are autokets of g(X) and f(X), respectively.

Comment: What is an autoket? Do you mean eigenket? Then yes, $|x\rangle$ is indeed an eigenket of $X$.